# Variable sysname sys.database

Tags: sql-server

Hi I want to ask i know it's simple but can't manage to solve this simple statement.

I'm trying to to create a adhoc script that will search a certain database. I'm using this one a sample of my script but having different result.

I have a database name MEL, but when I'm trying to query using `declare` and `set`, it did not show any database called Mel, but in the `sys.database` it exists.

```
declare @database sysname

set @database = ('Mel')

select name FROM master.sys.databases
where name = '@database'
```

---

```
use master
select * from master.sys.databases
where name = ('Mel')
```

Hope someone answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
select name FROM master.sys.databases
where name = @database
```

Your original query searches for a database with name `'@database'`, not the value of the variable `@database`.

Additionally, you can remove the parenthesis on the `set` statement.

```
set @database = 'Mel'
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)